# what is difference between foreach and delegate loop in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have read here http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/447223-foreach-list-foreach that someone tell that delegate loop is less performance then foreach commands.

Well i want to know what is difference between both. why foreach better and in which case we only need to use delegate looping.

Is there anyone who has compared both things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement those two solution and then compare them in IL.

Then you will know that is there some significant difference.

Regarding the performance write two apps, with some time diagnostic create a loop with 1mln entries and execute. Then at the end compare the execution time.

EDIT:

The difference might be in usage, using delegate you can perform operation on example string list by an uknow method

```
delegate StringListOperator(string s)

public operate(StringListOperator operator) {
   String.ForEach(operator);
}
```

I'n not 100% sure about syntax but i hope you got the point.

If You only plan to iterate through list in some method IMHO use simple foreach, this look like only a syntax sugar for me.

Comment: i know what you say but i thing to get what other know. if i really do that why i write this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that link: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33593372/delegate-vs-foreach-loop.aspx
In the question is your question and in the comments there are pretty good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Performance typically won't be a problem however you have to be careful of state capture when using the delegate vs the foreach loop.  Basically the compiler will copy variables used inside the loop that are not constants into a nested set of fields.  This can at times call undesirable effects